# Change navigation label for model in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

How to change navigation label in rails_admin?

Here is `app/models/admin.rb`:

```
module Admin
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'admin_'
  end
end
```

and `app/models/admin/seo.rb`:

```
class Admin::Seo < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I'd like to change the Rails Admin navigation label of the `Admin::Sea` model to "Admin".

I tried the following in `config/locales/ru.yml`:

```
activerecord:
    models:
      admin:
        one: test
        other: test1
      admin/seo:
        one: SEO - данные
        other: SEO - данные
```

Also I tried in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
config.model Admin do
   label 'test1'
   label_plural 'test1'
   navigation_label 'test1'
end
```

Comment: `Admin` is not a model it is a Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project it works like this

```
activerecord:
  models:
    admin/seo:
      one: SEO - данные
      other: SEO - данные
```

And you would not need your initializer.
Also it should be `ru.yml` not `en.yml` because it translation for Russian language so it must be used only for Russian locale.

**UPDATE 1**

I found some answer but I am not sure it is the best one (but it works)

```
class Admin::Seo < ActiveRecord::Base
  rails_admin do
    navigation_label I18n.t('your.translation.path.here')
  end
end
```

You can also put this code inside initializer not model (it is up to you).

You can see [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/helpers/rails_admin/application_helper.rb#L73-L85) how `rails_admin` generates this sidebar.
So each model should have `navigation_label` or it would be default `t('admin.misc.navigation')`.

**UPDATE 2**

You can set `navigation_label` for all the models during initialization like this

```
# config/environment.rb
...

RailsAdmin::Config.models.each do |model|
  if model.abstract_model.model_name.starts_with? 'Admin::'
    model.navigation_label I18n.t('your.translation.path.here')
  end
end
```

This will split all models with `Admin` namespace and other models into two separate menus in sidebar.
The code is placed in `environment.rb` because translations are not available in `initializers/*.rb`.

Comment: i'd like to change label to Admin
[img](http://savepic.ru/11435878.jpg)

Comment: I add $this code at my  seo.rb but nothing changed

rails_admin do
    navigation_label I18n.t('activerecord.models.admin')
  end

Comment: Do you have translation for activerecord.models.admin in you `.yml` file?
You can try `navigation_label 'foo'` and you will see the result.

Comment: gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
rails_admin (0.8.1)
rails_admin_rollincode (1.1)
`rails_admin do
    navigation_label "test"
    navigation_icon 'icon-user'
  end`

also not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123765/discussion-between-serhii-danovskyi-and-aleksey).